# MySQL concat select only if condition is valid

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

let's assume I've a table with these columns:

```
DATA1 | DATA2 | DATA3
```

I want to print: `DATA1 (DATA2)` if DATA2 is not null, only `DATA1` if `DATA2` is null. If I do it with a concat:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATA1," (",COALESCE(DATA2,""),")")
```

I've the problem that "(" and ")" are always printed, even if DATA2 is null, so I'll have as result: `DATA1 ()` instead of `DATA1`

Is there any way to do this with sql on mysql database?

Answer (score 5):

You've already got half the answer there. `CONCAT` will yield `NULL` if any of the values are null. You're using `COALESCE` so your entire result isn't null if `DATA2` is, so simply include the "()" inside the coalesce.

Try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(
              DATA1,
              COALESCE(
                         CONCAT(" (",DATA2,")")
                       ,"")
              )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT IF(DATA2 IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(DATA1, ' (', DATA2, ')'), DATA1) AS data;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple CASE:

```
SELECT CONCAT( DATA1, CASE WHEN DATA2 IS NULL THEN "" ELSE CONCAT( "( ", DATA2, " )" ) END ) 
FROM sometable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION statement to merge two result set. First result set will fetch data where DATA2 is null and in other result set will have DATA2 as null.